# Changing the maximum width of R markdown documents

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

When I create an R Markdown file and knit HTML, the following is present:

```
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I would like to change the max-width attribute. How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's no way to change that number specifically, but you *can* override it. Create your own `style.css` file in the same directory as your document, and give it some content:

```
body .main-container {
max-width: 500px;
}
```

Then reference that CSS file in your YAML front matter:

```
---
...
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
---
```

Comment: should I then include the header "css:" in ALL my files? Is there a way to set HTML width for the the subpages of my markdown project globally?...

Right now I am including 
`---
...
output:
  html_document:
    css: style.css
---`
in all my headers.

Comment: sure, R Markdown output options can be shared across all `.Rmd` files in a directory using [a separate YAML file named `_output.yaml`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#shared_options)

Comment: @Jonathan The above syles only work if I add the ` !important` rule to the `max-width` definition as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373846/7196903). But using that rule [seems bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception), so is there another way?

Answer (score 15):

If you are only making HTML output you can put

```
<style>
    body .main-container {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

at the beginning of the .Rmd file  I put mine after the front matter.